# How to get price data from Azure API for individual resources?

Tags: azure

I am using the API mentioned on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx to get the information on how much individual Azure resources is charging.

However I am getting a 401 response with error message as

> The 'Authorization' header is missing."

There seems to be lack of documentation on how to make the API call with proper authentication.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the call interactively, you can use the same `AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken` method the billing reference application is using to authenticate [example source.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api/blob/master/ConsoleApp-Billing-Usage/ConsoleProj/Program.cs)

If you want to call the billing API unattended from a service for instance, I have an example [here](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/02/calling-azure-billing-api-unattended/) using a service principal.